# Solving a recurrence: $\frac{1}{a_{n}}=\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}+\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

As in the title, solve such recurrence: $$\frac{1}{a_{n}}=\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}+\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}$$
for $n\ge 2$, where $a_1=2$ and $a_2=1$.

I mean, any hints?

Comment: Set $b_n = \frac1{a_n}$ to reduce the problem to its essence.

Comment: Guess it's too late for me now, this was really obvious.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Can you solve $$b_{n+1} = b_n - b_{n-1}\qquad n\geq 2$$ where $b_1=\frac{1}{2}$, $b_2=1$?

If so, can you define $(b_n)_n$ with regard to $(a_n)_n$ so that solving the above is equivalent to solving your original problem?

Comment: Guess it's too late for me now, this was really obvious.

Comment: @VanDerWarden To be honest, given the "right" amount of sleep-deprivation nothing is ever completely obvious.